# to remove text from a sentence in excel after numerics

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have tried a lot but could not find a way to remove the text from a cell after first numeric.

Let suppose there is a name of a file mentioned in excel where i would like to remove the remaining part of file name after the date (i.e. remove text right right side after date)

the formula i am using is =LEFT(A3,SEARCH("1",A3)-1)

in this formula it deletes the text after numeric 1 however there are many names where i have different numeric mentioned, therefore i could not find any solution so far

please see example below

[image]

Can anyone please advise if there any method to remove the text from right after every first numeric.

i will be thankful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula:

`=LEFT(A2,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A2 & "1234567890"))-1)`

Assuming that your names are in column A.

`MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A2 & "1234567890"))` returns the *first* = MIN position of each numerical value (1, 2, 3...)).  To assure that each figure occurs at least once "1234..." is added to the string to be checked.

`LEFT` obviously returns the left part of the string.