# Remove unnecessary text from row and split date from remaining text

Tags: excel, vba

Table in which I have to perform two functions
[image]

1. Filter out all text after "2022" because I need Actual file name and Date
2. Split Date with Actual file name, details in picture

I tried left and right function to remove the text.

Comment: Please include version of Excel and also edit your question to include the formulas and vba code that you tried.  Also, to make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: Regarding `Extracted Name`: you already accepted a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73660982/16578424 - why do you ask again?

Comment: Dear @IKE I have definitely tried the same formula =LEFT(A2,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A2 & "1234567890"))-1) but that is not removing the text appearing after "2022" but any numeric, i have tried a lot but could not

Comment: Dear @RonRosenfeld I have tried the formula mentioned below, not only this i have also tried to replace the text by ctrl H and 2022 but this way it is removing the year as well, therefore if there is any specific formula or method, this will be helpful. i do not have any VBA code for this purpose

Comment: Dear @RonRosenfeld i am using excel version professional plus 2019

Comment: with that version of excel you will need a user defined function (= VBA) that uses regular expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use regular expressions in VBA you have to add "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions" to your project references.

[image]

Then you can use this user definded function:

```vb
Public Function extractDate(rg As Range) As Date

Dim strDate As String:

strDate = extractText(" (\d{1,2} .{3} \d{4}) ", rg.text)
extractDate = strDate

End Function


Private Function extractText(pattern As String, text As String) As String
 Dim regEx As RegExp: Set regEx = New RegExp
 Dim regEx_MatchCollection As MatchCollection
 Dim regEx_Match As Match
  
 regEx.pattern = pattern

 Set regEx_MatchCollection = regEx.Execute(text)
 If regEx_MatchCollection.Count = 0 Then
      extractText = vbNullString
 Else
    Set regEx_Match = regEx_MatchCollection(0)
    extractText = regEx_Match.SubMatches(0)
 End If

End Function
```

You then use the formula like this:

[image]

Comment: Amazing, after writing the VBA code with the defined details i have then been able to write the function =extractdate and from this function i have extracted the date from Column and then used the formula =LEFT(A2,MIN(FIND({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},A2 & "1234567890"))-1) to remove un-necessary text. Amazing. Genius Sir.. bundle of thanks

Comment: I wish i could ask you if all these steps can be written in a code so that if i just press the Run button it performs all the steps defined. i.e. to ExtractDate from the formula and afterwards remove unnecessary text from Column A. Anyways whatever you have taught is also very very helpful. So kind of you sir